# PHP header или другой способ редиректа

Tags: php

Есть такой код, который не работает. Класс работает правильно, проблема только в функции header();

```
   <?php
include '../../classes/Band.php';
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
session_start();

$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $band = new Band($name);
    if(isset($_FILES['band_img']['name'])){
        $img = $_FILES['band_img'];
        $_SESSION['error'] = $band->addBand($img);
        if (!empty($_SESSION['error'])){
            $error = true;
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Фаил не выбран';
        $error = true;
    }   
}else{
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Введите название альбома';
    $error = true;
}

if ($error === true){
    header("Location: ../admin_templates/admin_template.php?s=0");
}else{
    header("Location: ../admin_templates/admin_template.php?s=1");
}

?>
```

Вопрос:

Как в данном случае реализовать переходы на другие страницы(шаблоны) в зависимости от значения флага?
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: вы избавьтесь от `..` для начала, глядишь и заработает.

Comment: Задавайте **по одному** вопросу, пожалуйста, приводя **только** относящийся к каждому код в каждом.

Comment: К сожалению выводит такую ошибку: "Сайт localhost выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз."

Comment: @ВадимВова такое может быть, если  у вас редиректы по кругу ходят. Можете открыть в браузере панель инструментов разработчика и на вкладке Сеть посмотреть выполняемые запросы.

Comment: @teran я думаю что оно так и есть, но как решить этот вопрос?)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($error === true){
    header("Location: http://www.test.com/admin_templates/admin_template.php?s=0");
    exit;
    // die(); - или можно так
}else{
    header("Location: http://www.test.com/admin_templates/admin_template.php?s=1");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Та же ошибка. Ничего не поменялось.

Comment: session_start в самое начало

Comment: попробуйте убрать GET параметр, если редирект произойдет нормально, то просто загоните s=0 в $_SESSION['s'] = 0. А в admin_template.php пропишите session_start();

Comment: и else со скобками можно убрать, он здесь не нужен

Comment: Все так же. У Вас с флагами такие редиректы нормально работают?

Comment: У меня все работает.

Comment: if ($error){
    header("Refresh:0; url=http://www.test.com/admin_templates/admin_template.php?s=0");
    exit;
}
header("Refresh:0; url=http://www.test.com/admin_templates/admin_template.php?s=1");
exit;

Comment: Еще один вариант, если не поможет, значит прописываете неправильный url.